# Verilog Structural description of an Edge-triggered T flip-flop with an synchronous reset (R)

Tags: verilog

I am trying to wire a Verilog Structural description of an Edge-triggered T flip-flop with an synchronous reset (R). Here is the circuit for this element:

[image]

Now assume that I have already written the behavioral description for each block in this schematic , so here is my structural description for this circuit by instantiation of each of this blocks in the circuit:

```
    module edge_trig_flipflop_structure (
input x,y,clk,
  output q,
  wire a,b,c,d
);
  inv u1(c,q);
  mux_2x1 u2 (q,c,x,a);
  inv u3(d,y);
  and_2_1 u4(b,a,d);
  d_flipflop u5(b,clk,q);
endmodule
```

Is this a good efficient code for this circuit? In other words, do I really need the two extra wires used for the inverters which are the wires `c` and `d`  Or, is there another efficient way to write this code?

Edit : Here is the code for each component to know the order of ports in the declaration of each component

```
module mux_2x1 (
input a,
input b,
input sel,
output reg c
);
 
  always @ (*) begin 
    case ( sel)
      1'b0: c=a;
      1'b1: c=b;
      default : $dispaly ("error");
   endcase
 end
        
  
endmodule 

module d_flipflop ( input d,clk , output reg q);

 always @ (posedge clk ) begin
   q=d;
      
  end 
  
endmodule
module inv(output reg b, input a);
  
  always @ (a) begin 
    b=~a;
  
  
  
  end
  
endmodule

module and_2_1 ( output reg c,input a,b);

always @(a or b) begin 
  if (a==1'b1 & b==1'b1)
    c= 1'b1;
  else
    c=1'b0;
  

end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Verilog does not require you to declare all signals.  If signals appear in port connections, they will implicitly be 1-bit `wire` types.

However, it is good practice to declare all signals explicitly with `wire`, as you have done.

You could also change the default behavior and require explicitly declared signals using this compiler directive:

```
`default_nettype none
```

---

Since you are also concerned about connections, it is a good practice to make connections by name instead of connections by position.  It is more verbose, but it will help avoid simple connection errors.  For example:

```
  inv u1 (.b(c), .a(q));
```

---

I got compile errors on your module header.  You probably meant to code it this way:

```
module edge_trig_flipflop_structure (
  input x,y,clk,
  output q
);

  wire a,b,c,d;
```